# Configure Django on Ubuntu Apache subdirectory

Tags: 14.04, apache2, python, django

I am running apache2 server on Ubuntu 14. Now I want to configure Apache to work with mod_wsgi to run Django on a subdirectory of a domain such as www.abc.com/lab, but I always fail to do that.

I have successfully installed Python by the way. I can do `python --version` which returns `Python 2.7.3`. The following are my steps of setting up:

1. I create a pylab folder under /var/www, inside has these files **init**.py, **init**.pyc, manage.py, settings.py, settings.pyc, and lastly urls.py
2. I then go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and create a lab file with the following contents:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>  
   ServerName /lab  
   DocumentRoot /var/www/pylab  
   <Directory /lab>  
   Options All  
   AllowOverride All  
   Require all granted  
   </Directory>  

   Alias /static/ /var/www/pylab/static/  
   <Location "/static/">  
   Options -Indexes   
   </Location>   

   Alias /media/ /var/www/pylab/media/   
   <Location "/media/">   
   Options -Indexes   
   </Location>   

   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/pylab/wsgi.py   
   WSGIDaemonProcess labapi python-path=/var/www/pylabprocesses=2 threads=15 display-name=Pylab   
   WSGIProcessGroup pylab   

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

But when I access www.abc.com/lab I only see a 404 error. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When hosting python, prefer to keep python source files outside `DocumentRoot`. Apache has a mod_wsgi module, compiled with some version of python. You can find this python version in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (Note: you may need to use sudo to read this file).

```
... mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.8 ...
```

**Install Python**

You have to use the same version of python in your project. If you want to use a different version of python you must compile python and mod_wsgi from source. Install these packages:

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
```

Download and compile python with at least optimizations and shared flags enabled. If you do not add `--prefix` then `make altinstall` instead of `make install`, otherwise it may overwrite the system python which can be fatal.

```
 ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --prefix=/opt/Python-3.8.2
 make -j4
 sudo make install
```

With `j4` in make, it will use 4 parallel process to compile.

**Install WSGI**

Moreover, you shall download and compile mod_wsgi from source. Install apache(-dev):

```
sudo apt install apache2 apache2-dev
```

and compile mod_wsgi with these flags.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Python-3.8.2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./configure --with-python=/opt/Python-3.8.2/bin/python3
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Open

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load
```

and prepend

```
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/Python-3.8.2/lib
SetEnv LD_RUN_PATH /opt/Python-3.8.2/lib
```

before

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

**Configure Apache**

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
sudo apachectl graceful
```

Let's now configure apache

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

In the VirtualHost section, write

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess sitename python-home=/path/to/project/venv python-path=/folder/containing/manage.py
    WSGIProcessGroup sitename

    #Static content
    Alias /static /path/to/project/static
    <Directory /path/to/project/static>
        AllowOverride None
        require all granted
    </Directory>

    #WSGI
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/wsgi.py.  # the path is inclusive of wsgi.py
    <Directory /path/contaning/wsgi.py>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
```

finally enable the site and gracefully restart apache

```
sudo a2ensite 000-default
sudo apachectl graceful
```

Visit `localhost` from any browser and it should be working.

If you want to host it in a sub folder 'lab', replace `WSGIScriptAlias` in apache-conf file with

```
SetEnv SCRIPT_NAME lab
WSGIScriptAlias /lab /path/to/wsgi.py.  # the path is inclusive of wsgi.py
```

and gracefully restart apache again.

References:

1. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-ubuntu
2. https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi