# mod_wsgi Call to fopen() failed for 'path/wsgi.py apache ubuntu

Tags: server, python, apache2

hi i try to deploy my django project `2.2v` on ubuntu apache server

when i run `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` i get this error:

> [time] [wsgi:error] [pid 13224:tid 2323232] (13)Permission denied: [remote some number:number] mod_wsgi (pid=13323, process='django_app', application='django_project|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/root/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py'.

my wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/django_proj.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /root/project_name/static
    <Directory /root/project_name/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /meida /root/project_name/meida
    <Directory /root/project_name/meida>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /root/project_name/zettapc>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /root/project_name/project_name/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/root/project_name python-home=/root/project_name/venv/
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app 

</VirtualHost>
```

and output of on my browser is :

> Internal Server Error

is there something i've missed please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder `/root` can be read by user root only. apache runs on Ubuntu as user `www-data`. Place it on a folder that can be read by user `www-data` such as `/opt/project-name` or `/var/www/project-name`. After copying it in such folder run the following command in the folder which contains the `project-name`

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data project-name
```

Thereafter it should stat working. You may take additional information from [Configure Django on Ubuntu Apache subdirectory](https://askubuntu.com/a/1261929/1107236)