# Ubuntu server with apache2 shows index of/

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, django

I am fairly new to the world of Ubuntu and apache2. And I've become a little confused of the directories and some other stuff.

1. I have read that the default web directory is `/var/www/`. I have my project in `/home/user/project`. Is that wrong?
2. Also I've actually gotten my project to work, a Django website, but right after I got the SSL-certification, it stopped working. I have tried to change the document root to the path where my project is, in every file. (`apache2.conf`, `website.conf`, `website-le-ssl.conf`). Can someone tell how I can get my site to work? NOTE: I am greeted with the page: 403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this resource.
3. I have tried some different configurations regarding my files (Mentioned above), and i have also been greeted by the: index of `/` page.

I really have no idea what to do now. I have searched on google, and the various forum, but nothing that i have tried works for me.

Comment: Regarding home directory projects: https://askubuntu.com/questions/767504/permissions-problems-with-var-www-html-and-my-own-home-directory-for-a-website/767534#767534

Comment: @ThomasWard so i have moved all my files and followed along with the steps that you have mention. Now i am getting the index of/ page with all the content of my project folder. How can i now get it to show the actual webpage?

Comment: You need to *serve* the Django application via WSGI either with Apache or uwsgi separately.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ as an example.  (I'm on my phone or I'd write an answer)

Comment: @ThomasWard I have followed the instructions on the page you linked, but i still only have the "Index of/" page.

Comment: This answer explains in detail how to set up a Django project with Apache2: https://askubuntu.com/a/1261929/1107236 . It may be of help.